# confliction errors between entirely different projects

Tags: php, cakephp

I created a 'tube/video site' powered by cakephp. It works great. I forked the tube site application into a new project that powers videos as well, but has different code.

After doing this, I began noticing errors that are completely unrelative to the current project. Example, my tube site will report an error that it can't find the Actors/Actresses model, but there's nowhere in the app that it is trying to load that model. It seems like my projects are causing conflictions with each other as if there should be some setting that is different to keep them from sharing similar resources.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: It maybe caused due to sql injection use form as post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had the same issue that my live application was throwing errors on behalf of my test application, which shouldn't even be aware of each other's presence.

It turned out that the Caching prefixes of both projects were the same and thus the caches interfered each other. Open your `app/Config/core.php` and change the default:

```
$prefix = 'myapp_';
```

To something unique, may be as simple as `app1_` and `app2_`, as long as they are different.
After doing so, make sure to clear your caches one more time, to force a rebuild (just delete the files in the `app/tmp/cache` subfolders).